# Using a class function in int main()

Tags: c++, class, unix, g++, pthreads

I am having problems calling my functions from my main program.
These functions HAVE to be in my class.
How do I access them from my int main()?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <synch.h>
using namespace std;   


class myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore {  
public:  
    void waitSemaphore(pthread_mutex_t *thread)  
    {  
        pthread_mutex_lock(*thread);// Makes value 1 (Not Available)  
    }  
    void signalSemaphore(pthread_mutex_t *thread)  
    {  
        pthread_mutex_unlock(*thread); // Makes value 0 (Available)  
    }  
    void deleteSemaphore(pthread_mutex_t *thread)   
    {  
        pthread_mutex_destroy(*thread);// Deletes  
    }  
};  
int readerCount;   
int database = (rand() / 100); // Number less than 1000  
void reader_writer(void);   
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{     
    myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore obj;  
    pthread_mutex_t mutex1;  
    pthread_mutex_t wrt;  
    pthread_create( &mutex1, NULL, reader_writer, void);  
    pthread_create( &wrt, NULL, reader_writer, void);  
    //----------------------READER------------------------//  
    do{  
        cout << "Database Before Read = " << database << endl;  
        obj.waitSemaphore(mutex1);//lock  
        readerCount++;  
        if (readerCount == 1)  
        {  
        obj.waitSemaphore(wrt);//lock  
        obj.signalSemaphore(mutex1);//unlock  
        //reading is preformed  
        obj.waitSemaphore(mutex1); // lock  
        readerCount--;  
        }  
        if(readerCount == 0)  
        {  
            obj.signalSemaphore(wrt);//unlock  
            obj.signalSemaphore(mutex1); // unlock  
        }  
        cout << "Database After Read = " << database << endl;  
    }while (true);  
    //-----------------------WRITER---------------------//  
    do{  
        cout << "Database Before Write = " << database << endl;  
        obj.waitSemaphore(wrt);//lock  
        //writing is preformed  
        database = database + 10;  
        obj.signalSemaphore(mutex1);//unlock  
        cout << "Database After Write = " << database << endl;  
    }while(true);  
    pthread_join( mutex1, NULL);  
    pthread_join( wrt, NULL);   
    obj.deleteSemaphore(* mutex1);  
    obj.deleteSemaphore(* wrt);  
    return 0;   
}  
void reader_writer () {}
```

Here is an error I get:

what type do they need to be? pthread_mutex_t_create? or pthread_t_create?
what is the proper type?

Comment: Could you please reduce your example or at least add an error you get

Comment: So which line exactly are you having trouble with? Or where would you like to call which function?

Comment: I want to call all of the functions in my class in my main body.

Comment: Please use code tags next time.

Comment: To format a block of code, select it and press the {} button. It is important that you do as @Elalfer suggests and reduce the code to a minimal example that shows the issue, and that you format the code and error to help others process the information. The best you can do is to help others in helping you.

Comment: I hope your compiler doesn't accept this.  `pthread_t` is a thread type, not a mutex type.  You're looking for `pthread_mutex_t`.  `man pthreads`.

Comment: how do I create a thread using pthreads_mutex_t

Comment: @ohlegend, you don't.  `pthread_t` represents a thread.  `pthread_mutex_t` represents a mutex.  `pthread_cond_t` represents a condition variable.  You seem to have these concepts confused.  I recommend you read more on these concepts in general and then follow some tutorial on pthreads in particular.

Comment: You don't create thread using pthreads_mutex_t but using pthread_create. Please better read some pthread tutorial and create few simple examples, before you start writing your project. This tutorial looks nice https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 2):

Functions inside a class are called methods. You need to instantiate an object of that class to be able to use it's methods:

```
myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore obj; // obj is an instance of the class

obj.waitSemaphore(&mutex1);

obj.signalSemaphore(&mutex1);
```

**EDIT:**

By the way, *pthread_create* and *pthread_join* take a `pthread_t*` and not a mutex!

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t* thread, 
                   pthread_attr_t* attr, 
                   void* (*start_routine)(void*), 
                   void* arg);
```

Comment: when I do this I get :                                   Source1.cpp:77: error: no matching function for call to 'myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore::deleteSemaphore (pthread_mutex_t&)'

Comment: When you are calling the method inside main(), you are not passing a pointer to the mutex, you passing the mutex itself. You must do it like `obj.deleteSemaphore(&mutex1);` instead of `obj.deleteSemaphore(mutex1);`

Comment: Your functions take a `pthread_mutex_t*`, a pointer. You try to pass a reference, to pass a pointer use `(&mutex1)`.

Comment: @ohlegend: When you dont have a matching function declared inside your `myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore`class. You have void `myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore::deleteSemaphore(pthread_mutex_t *)` and you are calling `myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore::deleteSemaphore (pthread_mutex_t&)'

Comment: @Xeo : Source1.cpp:74: error: cannot convert 'pthread_mutex_t' to 'pthread_t' for argument '1' to 'int pthread_join(pthread_t, void**)'
Source1.cpp:75: error: cannot convert 'pthread_mutex_t' to 'pthread_t' for argument '1' to 'int pthread_join(pthread_t, void**)'

Comment: The error msg is self explanatory: pthread_join() takes a `pthread_t` as a parameter, and you are trying to feed it with a `pthread_mutex_t`. Check the first parameter you are using in pthread_create(), it also must be `pthread_t`.

Comment: You seriously need to read a **pthread tutorial** before going any further: http://www.amparo.net/ce155/thread-ex.html

Comment: @ohlegend By the way, all your questions have been answered already. Consider accepting an answer! If you have any more questions we will be happy to answer them in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can either declare those methods as static or use an object to make the calls:

```
myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore s;
s.waitSemaphore(wrt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling class methods as just `waitSemaphore` without creating the object of myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore.

You should create the object first.

```
myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore obj;
obj.waitSemaphore(mutex1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The two threads you create (via `reader_writer()`) do nothing. `main()` just goes into the first `do` loop with no way of getting out.

Also, you seem to have confused mutex, semaphores, and condition variables. The function names makes it look like you're trying to implement condition variables in your class. But you're building it as just wrappers to mutex locks.

And finally, you are calling `pthread_mutex_lock()` et al. on a `pthread_t` when those functions are supposed to be called on a `pthread_mutex_t`.

There probably are other errors, but these are the ones that really jump out. Basically, you need to review multi-threaded programming, both in terms of how threads are created, and how they are synchronized.

Comment: @ohlegend, `pthread_mutex_t` is a mutex, not a thread.  You should probably read the tutorial referenced by Zuljin.

Comment: @ohlegend `pthread_mutex_t` is for a **mutex**. A **thread** is represented by `pthread_t`. You really need to read a tutorial on threads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the class (an object) in order to call his member functions.

In this particular code the member functions has no reason to be instance and could be static:

```
class foo{
    public:

    static void bar(int val)
    {
    //do something
    }
    };

int main()
{
   foo::bar(10);
}
```

Comment: Please write the compiler output.

Comment: By the way, Do you really have a reason to gather those functions under a class?

Answer (score 0):

karlphillip was right, you need to pass by pointer instead of reference

BTW, following line are mistake also, the pthread_create accept and pthread_t instead of pthread_mutex_t

> pthread_create( &mutex1, NULL, reader_writer, void);
>
> pthread_create( &wrt, NULL, reader_writer, void);

Comment: what type do they need to be?  pthread_mutex_t_create? or pthread_t_create?