# pthread_mutex_lock/unlock help

Tags: c++, unix, g++, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a class function in int main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624690/using-a-class-function-in-int-main)

I am trying to send a `pthread_t` var to a class function and I am having problems... I am trying to block and unblock threads by using the mutex. I am having a hard time understanding what to send.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <synch.h>
using namespace std;   

class myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore {  
public:  
    void waitSemaphore(pthread_t *thread)  
    {  
        pthread_mutex_lock(*thread);// Makes value 1 (Not Available)  
    }  
    void signalSemaphore(pthread_t *thread)  
    {  
        pthread_mutex_unlock(*thread); // Makes value 0 (Available)  
    }  
    void deleteSemaphore(pthread_t *thread)   
    {  
        pthread_mutex_destroy(*thread);// Deletes  
    }  
};  
int readerCount;   
int database = (rand() / 100); // Number less than 1000  
void reader_writer(void);   
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{     
    myCountingSemaphoreUsingBinarySemaphore obj;  
    pthread_t mutex1;  
    pthread_t wrt;  
    pthread_create(&mutex1, NULL, reader_writer, void);  
    pthread_create(&wrt, NULL, reader_writer, void);  
    //----------------------READER------------------------//  
    do{  
        cout << "Database Before Read = " << database << endl;  
        obj.waitSemaphore(&mutex1);//lock  
        readerCount++;  
        if (readerCount == 1)  
        {  
        obj.waitSemaphore(&wrt);//lock  
        obj.signalSemaphore(&mutex1);//unlock  
        //reading is preformed  
        obj.waitSemaphore(&mutex1); // lock  
        readerCount--;  
        }  
        if(readerCount == 0)  
        {  
            obj.signalSemaphore(&wrt);//unlock  
            obj.signalSemaphore(&mutex1); // unlock  
        }  
        cout << "Database After Read = " << database << endl;  
    }while (true);  
    //-----------------------WRITER---------------------//  
    do{  
        cout << "Database Before Write = " << database << endl;  
        obj.waitSemaphore(&wrt);//lock  
        //writing is preformed  
        database = database + 10;  
        obj.signalSemaphore(&mutex1);//unlock   
        cout << "Database After Write = " << database << endl;  
    }while(true);  
    pthread_join( mutex1, NULL);  
    pthread_join( wrt, NULL);   
    obj.deleteSemaphore(&mutex1);  
    obj.deleteSemaphore(&wrt);  
    return 0;    
}  
void reader_writer (){}
```